# creating svg node on ref with typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg

I am trying to create a ref on react+typescript:

```
class BarChart extends Component {
  private node: React.RefObject<SVGSVGElement | null>;
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.node = React.createRef();
  }
... 
}
```

this is the svg code i am trying to refer:

```
<svg ref={node => (this.node = node)} width={500} height={500} />
```

but i get this error:

```
Type 'SVGSVGElement | null' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<SVGSVGElement | null>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'RefObject<SVGSVGElement | null>'.
```

help? i am new in ts

Comment: use ref={this.node}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ref` attribute expects either `React.RefObject<TElement>`, or a callback `(TElement | null) => void`, or `null`.

There are two ways to make your code work:

1. Pass `this.node` to `ref` attribute:

   ```
       <svg ref={this.node} width={500} height={500} />
   ```
2. Change the type of `this.ref` to `SVGSVGElement | null`:

   ```
       private ref: SVGSVGElement | null = null;
   ```